# solve equation with integer maximum

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation, resolve

how to solve with Mathematica

a)$ \left  [\kern-0.10em\left[
 5 x  
\right]\kern-0.15em\right] = 2x+1$

b) $ \left  [\kern-0.10em\left[1/
 5 x  
\right]\kern-0.15em\right] > 2x+1$

EDIT = double square brackets is max integer

Comment: What do the double square brackets signify?

Comment: @march, I'm guessing the floor function, but OP really needs to clarify.

Comment: @J.M. Given the title, that seems like a reasonable inference, but yes, the OP needs to clarify.

Comment: Also unclear whether `1/5x` means `x/5` or `1/(5x)`.

Comment: @zeros I think you want the Floor function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Floor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor.html) and [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for part a.

```
Solve[Floor[5 x] == 2 x + 1, x, Reals]
```

> x -> 1/2

[image]

[`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) for part b (or a).

```
FindInstance[Floor[1/5 x] > 1 + 2 x, {x}, Reals]
```

> x -> -(109/5)

Comment: @zeros Does this not answer your question?